# How to show only two decimals in Data Table (DT R package) when using "filter" option?

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I am building a shiny app with some Data Tables (DT R package). I was able to round the columns using formatCurrency(), but I am not being able to round the numbers inside the filter, like is shown in the following image.[image]

I am using `renderDT({})`, with the following setup:

```
DT::renderDT({
df
},extensions = c(
  'ColReorder'
),
rownames = FALSE,
filter = c("top"),
options= list(
  search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE),
  pageLength = 6,
  lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 25, 50),
  colReorder = TRUE
), style = 'bootstrap'
)
```

Comment: My best guess if to make round function prior to the render, did you try this?

Comment: Yes, it works, but I don't want to change the data.